# Using exported component in another project

Tags: angular

I installed an internal component library that has components with export statement that I can use in my angular project.  I can import the component into my component through the import statement where it picks up the component name.  The question is how do I then just reference that in my HTML?  I setup on my constructor a 'private myComponent: MyComponent' but then do I need to initialize it I assume to then in my HTML file use ?  I only see the private myComponent greyed out.

Comment: You want to render 'MyComponent' in your html? And what is the name of the Module which is exporting 'MyComponent'?

Comment: Yes.  When I look at the component in the library in node modules it shows export declare class MyComponent implements OnInit.... I don't see a selector though that is where I am confused do I need to create a component within my project then add the selector etc. and just import that component there to use it?

Comment: what is the name of library you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the library module(Whatever you are using) in  imports in `AppModule.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule,LibraryModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and in `HTML`

```
<MyComponent></MyComponent>
```

Comment: When I add it to the imports in the app module it throws an error unexpected directive imported in app modules please add @ngmodules annotation.  I have the import where it recognizes it and then in the @NGModule imports I added it.

````
import { MyComponent } from 'library';

@NgModule({
declarations: [],imports: [MyComponent]
````

Comment: You should add the module name not component name

Comment: Okay got it so that is already there actually then in my component I added an import to the component itself I want to use but then dont I need to initialize it or something as the HTML alone says element tag does not exist

Comment: No need to import anything and initialize.. Firstly is it directive or component?

Comment: I figured it out I was in the wrong module it was in a project ngmodule.  Thanks a lot Supercool this helped me figure out where I was looking.  Thanks again